# vbs file saved as utf-8 does not run

Tags: vbscript

I have been writing a vbs script in notepad that adds text to an excel file, and this is working fine.

I then needed to write unicode characters to the excel file, so saved the vbs file as unicode and again all worked fine.

I am noe trying to write the file dynamically from another program, which is possible, but it writes the unicode vbs file as utf-8 formatting, and then when I try to run the vbs file, it gives an error 
saying error:invalid character
code:800A0408
Source:microsoft VBScript compilation error

Does this mean I cannot run a file saved as utf-8 formatting, or am I missing something?

Any help would be gratefully received!

Dave

Answer (score 3):

Use UCS-2 Little Endian, that accepts unicode chars and runs VBS properly! You can convert any existing VBS file to this format with notepad++ for example.

Answer (score 2):

C/WScript.exe can't run UTF-8 encoded .vbs files. If you can't change the encoding/write mode of that 'another program', you either have to convert the UTF-8 source to UTF-16 or write/generate the **code** in plain ASCII and inject the unicode **data** via ChrW() resp. an UTF-16 (easy) or UTF-8 (ADODB.Stream) encoded external file.

WRT comment:

As long as you don't use non-ascii characters in string literals - and you can avoid that for a few of them by using ".." & ChrW(..) & ".." - you can save the .vbs as ascii. If your 'another program' loads and saves such a file as UTF-8 (without BOM!) it doesn't matter; but if it adds a BOM you must convert the source file.

Perhaps you should add some more details/code to improve your chances of getting better advice.

Comment: Thanks for this reply, this is unfortunately what I thought. What I am trying to do is open a database connection, read in some unicode characters and write them to excel. Are you saying that the vbs file could be saved as ansi and this would still work?