# How to process special characters in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a find and replace workflow and it needs to be able to find special characters, one of which is a y with two dots above it.

https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00FF

I currently use a MACRO in Notepad++ to do this find and replace, but I need a bit more automation in this process.

The character code in Notepad++ shows &#x00FF

```
'Find and Replace 
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\TEST\" & JobNo & " " & strfolder & "\CustomerOriginals\" & FN, ForReading)

strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strText = Replace(strText, ChrW(00FF), "")


Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\TEST\" & JobNo & " " & strfolder & "\CustomerOriginals\" & FN, ForWriting)
objFile.WriteLine strText

objFile.Close
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please read the description for a tag before using it. VBScript, VB6 and VB.NET are all different languages and each tag specifies that it must not be used for questions about the others. Don't spam tags and try to trick people into reading questions irrelevant to them. People watch specific tags for a reason. Based on the title, I'm assuming VBScript and removing the other tags.

Comment: Is the file you're editing encoded as ANSI, UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Comment: Took a look in Notepad++ and show UTF-8

Comment: Note that the [Chr](https://ss64.com/vb/chr.html) and [Chrw](https://ss64.com/vb/chrw.html) functions take a decimal number as their argument, not hex. The `ÿ` character is code 255 in ANSII. In UTF-8 it may be represented by code 255 or the code pair C3 BF (195 191). You can't specify a code pair with Chrw. Use the actual character itself in the replace: `ÿ`.

Comment: Most answers you'll find will say that VBScript does not directly support UTF-8, so you will need to use the ADODB object. But VBScript will default to UTF-8 (for the functions needed in this case) as long as the script itself is saved as UTF-8.

Comment: Also relevant - [cscript.exe doesn't read unicode script (UTF-8)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33236085)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ADO to read and write UTF-8 files in VBScript, as per other answers on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4127011/15764378

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13855268/15764378

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15230319/15764378

But VBScript will handle UTF-8 for a simple read, replace, write as per this question, as long as the script itself is saved as UTF-8. Example:

**ReplaceChar.vbs**

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FP = "C:\Test\Test.txt"
Text = oFSO.OpenTextFile(FP,ForReading).ReadAll
Text = Replace(Text, "ÿ", "")
Text = Replace(Text, "", "")
oFSO.OpenTextFile(FP,ForWriting).Write(Text)
```

Note that VBScript does not actually support UTF-8. It cannot decode UTF-8 and display the correct character.

The example above works correctly whether the UTF-8 file is saved with or without BOM. The search, replace, and file write all work fine because a replace of  with  is just `F0 9F 99 82` being replaced by `F0 9F 91 8D`.

## Other solutions

You may also want to consider using PowerShell to do the character replacement. Here's an example:

**ReplaceChar.ps1**

```
$FP = 'C:\Test\Test.txt'
$Text = Get-Content -Path $FP
$Text = $Text -replace 'ÿ', ''
Set-Content -Path $FP -Value $Text
```

Comment: It handles Unicode (UTF-16,) by saving the script as UTF-8 you are just mimicking Unicode, but as UTF-8 can use up to four code units over Unicode's two to encode characters some characters will potentially mismatch. See [What are Unicode, UTF-8, and UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2241348).

Comment: @user692942 My test script above opens a UTF-8 text file and replaces both a two byte and a four byte UTF-8 character and correctly saves it back as UTF-8. Can you provide an example that will cause a mismatch?

Comment: I'm just saying it's possible, it's never good to treat different encodings the same regardless of how similar they are. Bear in mind that UTF-16 is the most restrictive of all the Unicode encodings. Also, as there is a proven alternative `ADODB.Stream` there is no reason to bend VBScript / FSO to process UTF-8.

Comment: @user692942 UTF-16 doesn't come into play here. Saving the script as UTF-8 just causes the default encoding to be UTF-8 instead of ANSI. The problem with using ADODB is that it triggers AV (typically a cross-domain false-positive). That being said, users really should switch to PowerShell when working with UTF-8 files.

Comment: Yes, but "Unicode" in Microsoft World is UTF-16, saving the script as UTF-8 means  (as far as [VBScript is concerned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543425/692942)) it gets processed as "Unicode". [VBScript (CScript / WScript) does not know how to process UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8756071/692942) it uses UTF-16.

Comment: @user692942 Maybe something has changed since those answers were posted because I have no problem running UTF-8 encoded scripts. That's not to say UTF-8 support has been added (there are situations where you may still have to use ADODB) but the scenario I described above works consistently.

Comment: VBScript / WSCript / Script hasn't changed in 20+ years. I've said my piece and your responses just highlight how little you understand character encoding, so let's leave it there. For clarity, I never said it wouldn't work but regardless UTF-16 (supported by VBScript via CScript and WScript command line switch) and UTF-8 are different encodings.

Comment: @user692942 I was incorrect in stating that UTF-8 encoding is used. The script is simply being treated as ANSI because it's saved as UTF-8 without BOM. I've added a note to my answer in that regard. I was correct in stating that UTF-16 does not come into play in this example. Everything in this example is handled as ANSI and it works fine because nothing is displayed by VBScript. The script is not processed as Unicode.

Comment: @user692942 I did some testing of scripts saved as UTF-16 and found that they display Unicode correctly both in Windows and the console without any need for `/u`. The font in the console matters, of course, but the use of /u (which is only available for cscript.exe) only appears to be needed to redirect output to a UTF-16 file. The behavior seems consistent with the official description for `/u` which states `Specifies Unicode for input and output that is redirected from the console`.

Comment: Yep, you’re right but still no direct support for UTF-8. +1