# VBS read content from opened csv file in utf-8

Tags: csv, file, vbscript

im trying to read from files, which are sometimes opened by users in Excel application and i cant close them.
i tried witd ADO Stream object, it gives me error "File could not be opened". when i close the file, it works fine.

```
Set oTxtStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
oTxtStream.CharSet = "utf-8"
oTxtStream.Open
Call oTxtStream.LoadFromFile(sMdmTestMetadataResults)
```

only method i found working is OpenTextFile() from FileSystemObject. but as i studied it, it reads with utf-16, but no utf-8.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set file = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\LOCAL\Jonas\resources\xls\MdmTestMetadata.csv", ForReading)
content = file.ReadAll
```

is there some way to get the file content in utf-8 from opened text files?

tried the methods describer in description

Comment: Your FSO example is using the default which is ANSI, not UTF-16. Depending on what you're doing, the ANSI mode may work perfectly fine for you. VBScript reads and writes a stream of bytes, so it will not corrupt a UTF-8 file. If you're displaying content using VBSCript, then it will display incorrectly, but if you're only processing the file, it should be fine. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76333693/15764378). What does your script do with the file?

Answer (score 0):

ADODB.Stream requires exclusive access to a file. You could try to first copy the open file to a temporary file using `fso.CopyFile`. CopyFile does not require exclusive access to a file. Then this temporary file can be read using ADODB.Stream. However, if an open file is copied, there is a risk that the integrity of the data is compromised.