# VBScript - How to encode Greek Characters in UTF8 as they appear incorrectly?

Tags: encoding, utf-8, vbscript, character-encoding

I have made a VBScript code to print Greek characters.
The issue here is that the characters appear incorrectly, even after my attempt to encode in UTF-8.

I am posting my VBScript code below:

```
MsgBox("Θραύσεις Κρυστάλλων") 'The text here appears as weird unreadable symbols because of the current default encoding

Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
stream.Open
stream.Type     = 2 'text
stream.Position = 0
stream.Charset  = "utf-8"

stream.WriteText "Θραύσεις Κρυστάλλων" 'here i supply the text again, to the Stream

stream.Flush
stream.Position = 0
stream.Type     = 1 'binary
stream.Read(3)      'skip BOM
utfStr = stream.Read
stream.Close
Set stream = Nothing

MsgBox(utfStr) 'Here I print the UTF8-encoded string from the stream. It appears different from the 1st messagebox, but still incorrectly
```

What could I be missing? Should I supply the Greek text via a text file instead, and avoid using variables?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are these characters saved correctly in the file (check with an editor)? So maybe MsgBox is not capable to show these characters.

Comment: Hello Shrotter! There's no file yet in this scenario.
I have tried sending an outlook email with these chars (via vbscript). They still do not appear correctly, so I don't think it's an issue with the capabilities of the MsgBox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vbs file saved as utf-8 does not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755850/vbs-file-saved-as-utf-8-does-not-run)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issues running JScript or VBScript files with UTF-8 encoding thru Windows Script Host](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22543425)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cscript.exe doesn't read unicode script (UTF-8)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33237552)

Comment: -there is no file in this scenario, the topic is solely about making the characters be printed correctly from within the variables, with the necessary encoding-

Comment: The "file" is the VBS file, the problem is that the scripting host that runs the VBS file can't process UTF-8, if you read through the suggested duplicates you would have understood that.

Comment: The `ADODB.Stream` approach should work, but why are you skipping the first three bytes, there is no BOM is this scenario, you are not loading in an UTF-8 encoded file?

Answer (score 1):

VBScript does not support UTF-8. It will handle UTF-8 as ANSI, so you can read and write UTF-8 files (since it will just be handled as a stream of bytes) but you cannot display the UTF-8 encoded characters correctly. You have two options:

## Option 1

**Save your script as UTF-16 LE**

MsgBox will display the characters correctly.

Note that, just like any other VBS script, the message box dialog will be displayed using DPI virtualization on displays that are set higher than 100% scaling. This makes the display blurry.

[image]

## Option 2

**Embed your VBS script in an HTA saved as UTF-8**

In this example, the HTA window is hidden by moving it off screen. If you wish to build a more sophisticated interface, then you could keep the HTA window on screen and use HTML/CSS to build your GUI.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">
<script language="VBScript">
Window.MoveTo 999999999,999999999
MsgBox "Θραύσεις Κρυστάλλων"
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

DPI virtualization is not used. The message box will display clearly and at the correct size, regardless of the display scale setting.

[image]

Comment: Good answer, a lot clearer than the existing ones. +1